iframe not showing Wordpress ACF
Iframe not being output in HTML.
Visible in Backend when switching to visual tab.
Can someone please inform me of why this code is being stripped from output? Is this ACF or something else? Saving the iframe code does seem to work in the WP backend (work = iframe output is visible) within the WYSWIG editor.



First, you should check if your iframe code is working properly. You can use another iframe code from Google Maps to test it.
Second, please check your output by PHP code.
Below I tested an example with WYSIWYG field including an iframe code from Google Maps and everything is working properly.


I use echo(get_field('iframe', 'option')); to show the field value from ACF.

Thank you for the tip. I will try a different Iframe and echo'ing the field.
